# How to extract objects from a dictionary into separate dictionaries

Tags: javascript

I have the following dictionary of keys and values:

```
{ 
  key1: { 
    name: 'Steve',
    position: 1
  },
  key2: { 
    name: 'Bob',
    position: '2'
  }
}
```

All I want to do is to extract them into an array of separate dictionaries. How do I do this?

Comment: What is the expected output? It's unclear whether you want values, key value pairs or just an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
let obj = {key1: { name: 'Steve',position: 1},key2: { name: 'Bob', position: '2'}}

let arr = Object.keys(obj).map(e=> ({[e]: obj[e]}))

console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.values` to get the values as separate arrays.

```js
let obj = { 
  key1: { 
    name: 'Steve',
    position: 1
  },
  key2: { 
    name: 'Bob',
    position: '2'
  }
}

let array = Object.values(obj)
console.log(array)
```

Answer (score 0):

> All I want to do is to extract them into an array of separate
>   dictionaries. How do I do this?

You can use `Object.entries()` or `Object.values()`